# problems with extended classes and overwrite with methods

Tags: c#, .net, partial-classes, overwrite

I have a .net website written in C# and will make functionalities that other developers can use.
So I will make some default implementation and a developer can overwrite some methods

Example:
i have a class `ShoppingCart` and a class `Product` the class product haves a method `getProductPrice`
the shoppingcart will call the method `getProductPrice` for calculating the total price of cart

The `ShoppingCart` and `Product` are in the same project and i will give the developers the .dll so they can't change the source code so we can update the assembly later

So they need to make a other project and extend the product class and overwrite the method `getProductPrice` so they can implement there own logic
The problem is that the shoppingcart will not call the extended method but the original

If we make already a extended project for the developers and the shoppingcart will call the extended method then we have a circular reference
because the extended product needs a reference to product and the shopping cart to the extended product

Partial classes also don't works because we only can use partials within the same assembly

Does anyone have a suggestion ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The term is "override", not "overwrite"

Comment: did any of the answers help at all? Do you need any further assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mark all your `Product` methods as [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
public virtual decimal GetProductPrice() { };
```

Then the developers who will take over later can inherit from the product and override the method:

```
public class OverriddenProduct : Product
{
   public override decimal GetProductPrice() { }
}
```

Because `OverridenProduct` (in my example above) inherits from `Product`, it can still be added into the `Product` collection within your `ShoppingCart` class.

Just symantics I guess, but the ShoppingCart class's method should probably be `GetTotalPrice()` not `GetProductPrice()` as I'm assuming you're getting the total cost of the products in the cart.

Comment: Trying to implement it, changing some logic and classes but i think this is a solution

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method as a virtual method. That allows you to override it in an inheriting class so that any calls to it will always be routed to the overriding implementation. [More about virtual methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=VS.71).aspx).

Also, `GetProductPrice` sounds like something that might be better to implement as a property instead of a method.